# Rebuilding proto files from Android apps

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, protocol-buffers

I found a link describing how to rebuild proto files from a C++ executable:  http://www.sysdream.com/reverse-engineering-protobuf-apps
Is there a similar method for APKs or decrypted objective c apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you linked describes extracting the `FileDescriptorProto`s embedded as string literals in a C++ application that uses Protobufs.  The Java code generator embeds similar string literals into Java code.  If you ran the Java classes through a decompiler, you should be able to recover the descriptor strings and decode them.

However, note that this only works if the application uses the standard, Google-authored Java protobuf implementation and does *not* use "lite mode".  In lite mode, descriptors are not included in the generated code.  Implementations other than the Google-authored ones may or may not include the descriptor.  I would guess that most Android developers prefer to use lite mode or some alternative lightweight implementation that doesn't include descriptors, so you might have trouble extracting from APKs.  (I don't know about objective C.)

That said, note that you can actually decode a lot of the information in a protobuf message without having the schema at all.  If you use `protoc` with the `--decode-raw` command-line option and feed it a protobuf message on stdin, it will decode it to tag/value pairs.  You'll only get numbered fields (not names) and some type information is lost, but you'll find it much easier to reverse-engineer the format from there than you would with just the raw bytes.

Comment: Well it's an app by Google, so it'd almost certainly use the Google-authored implementation. Where would this embedded code be found? I haven't had much luck finding it

Comment: The class I'm interested in extends MessageNano. Would that contain the strings?

Comment: Sorry, it sounds like the app you're working with is using the "nano" implementation of protobufs created by one of the members of the Android team.  This is an alternative implementation created specifically for Android and almost certainly doesn't have the protobuf descriptor embedded.  You might still be able to figure out the schema by looking at the decompiled code (e.g. looking at the method names), or using `--decode-raw`.